# How to solve equation such polynomial: $x^3-bx^2+c=0$ in real domain

Tags: polynomials

the question just like in the title:

How to solve  $x^3-bx^2+c=0$ for x analitically, when b and c are constants, and all (coefficients and variables) are reals.

Comment: Look up "Cardano's formula" and especially the method used to get it.

Comment: Though big one see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots)  and scrolling down you'll see special cases your's too which can be solved using Cardano's method.

Comment: If you put $y=\frac 1 x$ you will get a cubic in $y$ without a term in $y^2$ - which is an alternative to the standard method of setting $x=y+b/3$

Answer (score 3):

The first step when solving an arbitrary cubic is to get rid of the quadratic term (the term in $x^2$).  We do this by 'completing the cube' - a process analogous to completing the square for quadratics.

Specifically, we make the substitution $y=x-\frac{1}{3}b$.  Then:

$$
y^3 = \left(x-\frac{1}{3}b\right)^3 = x^3 - bx^2 +\frac{1}{3}b^2x-\frac{1}{27}b^3
$$

Combining this with our equation $x^3-bx^2+c=0$ gives us:

$$
y^3 - \frac{1}{3}b^2y-\frac{1}{9}b^3+c=0
$$

And we now have a cubic of the form $y^3 - \alpha y + \beta=0$ (A much nicer way to get this form, as Mark Bennet points out, is to use the substitution $y=\frac{1}{x}$.  Then you end up with the cubic equation $y^3 - \frac{b}{c}y+\frac{1}{c}=0$).

Anyway, suppose you have a cubic equation of the form $y^3-\alpha y+\beta=0$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real and $\alpha$ is positive.  It is a theorem of Galois theory that there is no solution by radicals (i.e., a solution entirely in terms of the coefficients $\alpha$ and $\beta$, where you're allowed to use $+$, $-$, $\times$, $/$ and take roots) of an arbitrary cubic equation that lives entirely in the real numbers.  That is to say, even if the coefficients are all real and the solutions are all real, you might still have to get your hands dirty using complex numbers.  I wrote an essay a long time ago detailing how that's done, which you can find [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3-eWwU682JaTEFja0FSTXFldWM/edit?usp=sharing), or you can look up 'Cardano's method' to see how to do it with complex numbers.

There is, however, a way to get real solutions to a cubic with real coefficients that does not involve complex numbers.  It's not a solution by radicals, since it uses trigonometric functions, but it's still quite nice.  Note that it is important that $\alpha$ be positive for this to work.  We first make the substitution $y=u\cos\theta$ and note the standard trigonometric identity:

$$
4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta=\cos(3\theta)
$$

It turns out that we can choose $u$ in such a way that our cubic equation $y^3-\alpha y + \beta$ turns into this identity.  The correct choice turns out to be $u=2\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{3}}$ (see if you can derive this for yourself).  Then our cubic becomes:

\begin{align}
y^3-\alpha y + \beta &= u^3\cos^3\theta-\alpha u\cos\theta + \beta \\
&=8\frac{\alpha}{3}\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{3}}\cos^3\theta-2\alpha\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{3}}\cos\theta+\beta \\
&=\frac{2\alpha}{3}\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{3}}\left(4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta\right)+\beta \\
&=\frac{2\alpha}{3}\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{3}}\cos(3\theta)+\beta
\end{align}

From here, it's pretty easy to find $\cos(3\theta)$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and hence to compute $\theta$.  Then, setting $y=u\cos\theta$, we are done.

Comment: For $\alpha > 0$ you can use the identity $$4 \sinh(x)^3 + 3 \sinh(x) = \sinh(3x). $$

Answer (score 0):

$x^3-bx^2+c=0$ is continue and we know that a polynomial from n degree cant have more than n root.so you must find that where that $x^3-bx^2+c$ have change at it's sign then you can find roots are in which interval

Comment: yeah, but it's rather somewhat a numerical approach